# ReflectionException in laravel. Class does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Why does laravel cannot detect my class this time. In my previous tries it worked but this time it does not. Here are my codes :

**DataEntry.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Server ;
abstract class DataEntry{
    /*This class facilitates the
     storing of data to the  server...
     */
    abstract protected function storeData($data);
    abstract protected function updateData($data ,$id);
}
```

**MedicineDosageEntry.php**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Server ; 
use Image; 
use App\Dosage ; 
use App\Photo ;
use App\Server\DataEntry ;  
use Request ; 
use Auth ;

class MedicineDosageEntry extends DataEntry{
    public function storeData ($data){
        $file = $data['photo'] ; 
        $fileName = uniqid().$file->getClientOriginalName() ; 
        if(!file_exists('medicine/images')){
            mkdir('medicine/images', 0777, true);
        }
        $file->move('medicine/images', $fileName);

        if(!file_exists('medicine/images/thumbs')){
            mkdir('medicine/images/thumbs', 0777, true);
        }

        $thumb = Image::make('medicine/images/' .$fileName)->resize(150,150)->save('medicine/images/thumbs/' . $fileName,50);
        $dosage = new Dosage;
        $dosage->dosage_name = $data['dosage_name'];
        $dosage->form = $data['form'];
        $dosage->medicine_id = $data['medicine_id'];
        $dosage->price = $data['price'];
        $dosage->save(); 

        $dosage->photo()->create([
            'dosage_id' => $data['id'];
            'file_name' => $fileName,
            'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
            'file_mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
            'file_path' => 'medicine/images/thumbs'. $fileName,
            'created_by'=> Auth::user()->id,
            ]);
    }


    public function updateData($data , $id) {

    }
}
```

MedicineController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DB\MedicineRepository;
use App\Http\Requests\MedicineRequest ;
use App\Dosage ;
use App\Medicine;
use Auth ;

use App\Server\MedicineDosageEntry ; 
use Flash ;

class MedicineController extends Controller {

public function store(MedicineRequest $request, MedicineDosageEntry $dosage ){
        $requestData = $request->all();
        $dosage->storeData($requestData);
    }

}
```

Do i have to register this class. Why do I encounter this. It worked out in my previous tries but after doing some refactoring and coding. It crashed..

[image]

Comment: What class is it failing to find?

Comment: Class App\Server\MedicineDosageEntry does not exist

Comment: Have you tried composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Yeah I tried it. still does not work

Comment: Please post your file structures

Comment: Next thing would be to check folder structure as @AliMohammed mentioned. Please update the post with a screenshot of your folder structure within the app directory.

Comment: Seems like your folder structure / namespaces are correct. Can you please post the autoload part of the composer.json folder? I'm assuming it's psr4

Comment: Now that's the part I do not know. So I have to post the composer.json here ?. Am I right ?

Comment: ``
"autoload" : {
    "classmap" : [
    "database"
    ],
    "psr-4" : {
     "App\\" : "app/"
    }
    },

```